# For Drupal 7, is there a hook debug mode equivalent to the theme debug mode?

Tags: 7, debugging

As a beginning developer, it seems like I spend a significant percentage of my time googling to find out what hook to call in order to modify something before it renders.

In the [drupal 7.33 release](https://groups.drupal.org/node/448448), the `theme debug mode` was introduced, which provides contextual information in the page's HTML to theme developers and can be accessed by setting the `theme_debug` variable to `TRUE`.

Obviously there is no `hook debug mode` supported in core, but is anyone aware of a module that would provides contextual information about attempted hook calls, similar to how `theme debug mode` displays theme suggestion attempts?

Specifically, I am wondering if there is a module that would generate a list  of every call to `drupal_alter()`, `module_invoke_all()`, or `module_invoke()`, along with the `$type`, `$module`, and/or `$hook` arguments supplied to these functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom module and use [hook_module_implements_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7) which takes two arguements - $implementations and $hook.

Try this:

```
function MODULE_module_implements_alter(&$implements, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'form_alter') {
    print_r($implementations);
  }
}
```

This will print out a list of all the implementations, in order, for hook_form_alter.

Comment: Good answer, but it won't work for calls to `module_invoke()`, which doesn't use `module_implements()`. I might be wrong, but I think a couple of core patches would be the only way to reliably get what the OP wants

Comment: I would never recommend modifying the core :)